# I want to implement webview.postUrl in Ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, webview, inappbrowser

I am in the middle of one project that needs payment integration. But In native, they are using webview to handle payment gateway as follows:

```
webview.postUrl(URL, URLEncoder.encode(data.toString(), "UTF-8").getBytes());
```

I want to implement same in Ionic framework. I have tried following method with help of InAppBrowser plugin in hope to get the same result:

```
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(URL, '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: URL,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

But I am not getting response with this.

So, My kind request to you all that help me out to implement "webview.postUrl" in Ionic?

> It is also be helpful if anyone of you can make ionic or cordova plugin and then publish it. because many like me would facing this problem right now.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got success to get the same result as webview.postUrl.

I have implement following code in my app.

```
var URL = "https://www.yoururl.com"; // your url

var pageContent = "<html><head></head><body><form id='loadform' action='" + URL + "' method='post'>" +
    "<input type='hidden' name='keyname' value='" + value + "'>" +
    "</form> <script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('loadform').submit();</script></body></html>";
var pageContentUrl = "data:text/html;base64," + btoa(pageContent);

var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(
    pageContentUrl,
    "_blank",
    "hidden=no,location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes"
);
```

Here you can see that I am making simple html form with input field in it. That input field holds my data's key and value (same as json).

This method works well in both Android and iOS.

Thank you all who have invest their valuable time for trying to help me.